# Duplicating the value of one input to another input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a range input field and a text field. I would like to move the slider to duplicate the resulting number in the text field. This was done successfully. But I would also like that when you enter a number in the text field, this number is also set in the range input. That's where it doesn't work out.

It is important that the cost changes exactly from the range input. The text field would be useful for convenience.

I use this code and it works correctly, copying data from range input to a text field. But there's no way back

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.amount_range1').change(function(){
            var val = jQuery('.amount_range1').val();
            jQuery('.amount_text1').val(val);
        });
     });
```

The page with this slider and field is here https://mmogoldstore.com/product/world-of-warcraft/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you provide more information about how the slider works. It is unlikely that people will debug your site just to find that out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't speak English well, I write through a translator, so it's difficult to explain how range field functions, so I left a link to the page with it.

Comment: Sergey, I will not review your site in order to answer this question. You might want to create a JSFiddle where you provide a reproducible example of the issue. That would help you think through what the issue is and help me understanding the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the job.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".amount_range1").change(function () {
    console.log("test");
    var val = jQuery(".amount_range1").val();
    jQuery(".amount_text1").val(val);
  });
  
  jQuery(".amount_text1").keyup(function () {
    console.log("test");
    var val = jQuery(".amount_text1").val();
    jQuery(".amount_range1").val(val);
  });
});
```

It would work with `change` but then the inputfield must be deselected.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I tried it, I'm sorry I didn't write it right away.

Comment: Have a look at this [Pen](https://codepen.io/redjohn360/pen/zYqKgOK) maybe you can find something

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just add the same script reverted ?

```
jQuery('.amount_text1').change(function(){
            var val = jQuery('.amount_text1').val();
            jQuery('.amount_range1').val(val);
        });
```

Just in the same block of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // ... here
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I tried it, I'm sorry I didn't write it right away.